# Perl glob and filehandle problems

Tags: perl, glob, filehandle

Ok, I have a bit of an issue here. I realize that I don't need to set a $handle to *::HTML to get this snippet to work, however this code is taken out of context from its use and I do in fact need this to work with the $handle. The output I am receiving is below the snippet however the output I want is for the file.html to contain "what\nsometext1\nsometext2\n".

```
open(HTML, ">file.html");
$handle = \*::HTML;
print $handle "what\n";

open(READ, "< somefile.txt"); #somefile.txt contains sometext1\nsometext2\n
while(<READ>)
{
    print $handle;
}
close READ;
close HTML;
```

file.html is left with the output "what" and GLOB(0x6278b0)GLOB(0x6278b0) is printed to terminal window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) you will see that there are three valid ways to call `print`:

- print FILEHANDLE LIST
- print LIST
- print

Only the last version prints `$_` implicitly.  The reason for this is simple, Perl can't tell if you mean to print the filehandle or to the filehandle without more information (the whitespace separating the filehandle and the list).  Printing the filehandle (rather than to it) is the most flexible method, so they chose that resolution of the ambiguous case.

Comment: Actually, "print HANDLE" uses $_ as well, but perl parses an ambiguous scalar as "print LIST" instead. (And "print {$fh}" is a syntax error.)

Answer (score 6):

When you use scalar variables to hold filehandles you have to help Perl understand how to parse the expression. Saying `print $var` is ambiguous. It could mean either of the following:

```
print STDOUT $var;  # print the contents of $var to STDOUT
print {$var} $_;    # print the contents of $_ to the handle $var
```

Perl picks the former. If you want the latter, you need to make it explicit by bracketing the filehandle to disambiguate it.

Furthermore, Perl only uses the default variable `$_` when you don't supply any arguments for what to print. Because of how `print $var` is interpreted, `$_` isn't used.

Answer (score 3):

Perl's [print operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) does allow omission of LIST in all cases. Consider:

```
$ perl -le '$_ = "foo!"; print STDOUT'
foo!
```

But that looks to the parser like a filehandle—unlike `print $scalar`, which could be anything at runtime. If you're unsure of the parse for a bit of code, feed it through [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html), as in

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p try
while (defined(($_ = <READ>))) {
    print($_);
    print($handle);
    print(STDOUT $_);
}
```

As written, the loop contains three calls to print: `print`, `print $handle`, and `print STDOUT`.

To get close to what you want, you might use [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html):

```
my $oldfh = select $handle;

while(<READ>)
{
    print;
}

select $oldfh;
```

Note that select returns the previously-selected filehandle, and the code above saves it so as to put things back where we found them afterward.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out; I need the `$_` after `$handle` for this.

Comment: print is context sensitive -- with a single argument, it assumes you want to print to STDOUT; with two or more arguments, it takes the first one to be the glob you want to print on. And because you specified an argument to print already, $handle, it won't use $_ as a default argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $html, '>', "file.html" );
print $html "what\n";

open( my $read, '<', "somefile.txt" ); #somefile.txt contains sometext1\nsometext2\n

while( my $line = <$read> )    {
    print {$handle} $line;
}

close $read;
close $html;
```